# How to make "Give me updates for other Microsoft products" enabled again?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I installed the Creators Update (version 1703) on my Windows 10 Pro computer, but now I get updates for Microsoft Office when I try to update Windows. I checked the advanced settings and found the option *"Give me updates for other Microsoft products"* is unchecked and disabled. There is also text at the top that says *"Some settings are hidden or managed by your organization."*

How do I stop receiving updates for other Microsoft software and make that option *"Give me updates for other Microsoft products"* enabled ?

**Edit:** I really need to find a way to make this option enabled again.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this computer on a domain and/or is Group Policy being used?

Comment: none being used

Comment: next time use my linked tool and change the source. it does everything you want

Comment: the tool sets the policy setting. But do what ever you want, I'm out here

Comment: Being on **Windows Server 2016**, the only thing that worked for me was to delete the "**AU**" sub key from "`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate`" via RegEdit. [Tip from here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2d6a42d2-3186-4356-80be-6225b6968220/give-me-updates-for-other-microsoft-updates-is-greyed-out?forum=ws2016). I still needed to reboot and enter the "Advanced options" in the update panel several times, until the check box came up enabled.

Comment: +1 for @UweKeim's suggestion of deleting the AU sub key.  The solution for me was after deleting, to perform a manual "check for updates", then Advanced Settings, then repeat those two processes a couple of times.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like something potentially configured the **Local Group Policy** on that machine that affects Windows Updates.  To double-check, open the `Local Group Policy Editor` by searching for `gpedit.msc` and choosing `Run as administrator`, then navigate to the following location:

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update

On the right-hand side, double-click the policy to `Configure Automatic Updates`.  If it is `Not configured`, it should look like this:

[image: Configure Automatic Updates]

If it **is** configured, you have the option to switch it to `Not configured` accordingly and that should allow you to regain control within the `Settings` interface.

On the other hand, if the `Configure Automatic Updates` is already set to `Not configured`, it's possible that something changed the associated registry keys that correspond to those Windows Update settings.  To verify that, open the `Registry Editor` by searching for `regedit` and choosing `Run as administrator`, then navigate to the following location:

> HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\

In the screenshot below, the only value that appears on the right-hand side is there because I have configured my system to not install device drivers within Windows Update:

[image: Windows Update Registry]

If you see additional values on the right-hand side, something configured your system in that regard and may be causing the problem.  You can potentially delete those DWORD values to restore functionality, but I would urge you to proceed with caution and export the `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\` hierarchy to a `.reg` file first.

(Source:  [Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250))

Comment: yes setting `Configure Automatic Updates` to enabled helped me and the option is now enabled. registry is the same like you.... thanks

Comment: Always glad to help!

Comment: Be wary, the `some settings are hidden or managed by your organization` flag means that group policy restricted your settings, but it normally also means it was done at a company/enterprise level.  The setting you just changed might get changed back by a central authority.  (example: I handle am one of the GPO guys at my company, and if you made that change in local policy it'd be reset within a week here.)  That's because the central authority wants you to get the uniformed settings and download the updates they send you, regardless of what you want.

Comment: @Ruscal, certainly good advice and I understand where you are coming from:  at work, I manage the GPO architecture for three domains.  However, I thought it was relatively safe to assume that this isn't a domain workstation because the OP emphasized that they installed the Windows 10 Creators Update themselves, and that it is a Windows 10 Pro machine.  Yes, those *can* join an Active Directory domain, but Windows 10 Enterprise is much more common at the corporate level. Regardless, thanks for the feedback and hopefully the OP will chime in to help clarify the situation for us.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

- Go to Run, type `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to `Computer Configurations -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update
- In the right hand window double-click `Configure Automatic Updates`, set it to `Not configured` and click Apply.
- Go to  Start -> Settings -> Update & security -> Windows Update, click on `Check for updates`. Once it finishes saying "Your device is up to date", click Advanced options.
- `Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows` should now be available.

If this does not work, try running Control Panel / Troubleshooting, and under
System and Security, click on "Fix problems with Windows Update" and follow
the indications.

Comment: read my question again the option is disabled

Comment: Sorry, the rewritten answer may be more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the 3rd party tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](http://m.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_update_minitool.html) which allows to select which updates can be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do:
>  • Check
>   for updates 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • Hiding unwanted updates
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • Configure Automatic Updates
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader

Here you can change the checking mode to only notify about updates and download the updates manually when you want. You can also change the `update service` entry from Microsoft Update to Windows Update to only get Windows updates.

[image]

Comment: The WUMT link seems to be dead now (pointing to an empty blog).

Comment: @UweKeim I replaced it with a link to majorgeeks. There is also a [similar tool](https://github.com/DavidXanatos/wumgr) which is also open source