# Windows 10 downloading same updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, updates

[image]

Best part, I don't even have these programs installed on the machine. I did before, but I uninstalled them and these updates keep downloading and installing every couple days. I uninstalled office 2013 because I was planning on office 2016. I uninstalled Skype for Business because I use normal desktop/tray version and I never used SkyDive nor Outlook.

https://superuser.com/a/576520/306306 does not solve.

Performed `sfc /scannow` and `dism` commands.

Comment: use [this tool to control which updates](https://superuser.com/a/1200266/174557) you want to install. you can also hide updates with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

check this similar case for hints, I suggest to run Windows Update troubleshooter at first.

https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1276256-windows-updates-tries-to-install-office-2013-patches-after-2016-install/

Besides, before installing Office 2016, please check registry and installation directory to see if there is any item about Office, if there is, delete them. Same behaviors for Skype for business.

Regards